# sql query in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a document and an embedded document as shown below. And I would like to query the embedded document in mongoengine. In sql, this would be: SELECT A.Nom_PC, B.Intitule from Comptes as A, Vals as B WHERE B.Num = "some value"

```
class Vals(EmbeddedDocument):
    Num = StringField()
    Intitule = StringField()
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class Comptes(Document):
    Nom_PC = StringField()
    PC = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Vals))
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
```

I've tried out some things that didn't work like:

```
Comptes.objects(Vals__match={ "Num": Num }).aggregate(
       {'$project': {
           'PC': {
               '$filter': {
                   'input': '$PC',
                   'as': 'Vals',
                   'cond': {'$eq': ['$$Vals.Num', Num]}
               }
           }
       }}
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you really should use

```
PC = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Vals)
```

instead of

```
PC = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Vals))
```

This is because lists of embedded documents require special considerations.

As to the query:

```
q = Comptes.objects(PC__Num="some value")
```

This creates a query for all matching `Comptes` documents. You can then cherry pick whatever data you wish from each document.

(If, in the future, you need to match on multiple items in an EmbeddedDocument, use the `match` keyword. See the docs for more info.)

For example:

```
my_list = []
for doc in q:
    for v in doc.PC:
        if v.Num == "some value":
            my_list.append([doc.Nom_PC, v.Intitule])
```

For a YouTube vid I made with further details about the EmbeddedDocumentListField: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajwPOyb6VEU&index=6

Comment: If you don't mind me asking another question, I'd also like to insert new values of Num and Intitule at a certain position for example i have an index i that corresponds to the position of specific Vals.Num and Vals.Intitule i want to know how to create that index (cause i think an embedded document doesn't have an id by default) and then how to insert the new values right after that index

Comment: For one particular document that is already loaded into memory, just use standard Python practices. When the structure of a list is altered, the whole list is saved on update. So, for example, if the document is loaded in `d` and a new EmbeddedDocument is `v`, then to insert that entry at index 2, use `d.PC.insert(2, v)`. Then, of course, `d.save()`.